# Using many connection.cursor()

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I want to fetch data from 3 tables in a single database at once. I used 3 conn.cursor() to it.. Are there any sophisticated ways to do it?

```
            conn = psycopg2.connect(database="plottest", user="postgres")
            self.statusbar.showMessage("Database opened Sucessfully", 1000)
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur1 = conn.cursor()
            cur2 = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT id ,actual  from \"%s\" " % date)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            cur1.execute("SELECT qty from DAILY where date = \'%s\'" % date)
            dailyqty = cur1.fetchone()
            cur2.execute("SELECT qty from MONTHLY where month = \'%s\'" % month)
            monthqty = cur2.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Awoogah awoogah, SQL injection warning!** Don't write code using string interpolation. What happens if someone calls your code with the "date" `');-- DROP TABLE DAILY;--` ?

Use bind parameters. Always.

The only exception is for dynamic identifiers, like in the case above where you seem to use a table named after the current date. In that case you *must* `"double quote"` them and double any contained double-quotes. In your case that means that `date` should be `date.replace('"', '""')` where you substitute it into the SQL.

---

Now, back to our regular programming.

Since you `fetchall` from each cursor you can just re-use it. You don't need new cursors each time.

You can also combine the daily and monthly stats if you want, with a `UNION ALL`. I fixed your capitalisation and parameter binding in the process:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT 1, qty FROM daily WHERE date = %s
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 2, qty FROM monthly WHERE month = %s
               ORDER BY 1""",
            (date, month))
```

Note that string interpolation isn't used, instead a 2-tuple of parameters is passed to `psycopg2` to bind directly. There's no need for quotes around the parameters, `psycopg2` adds them if needed.

This avoids a client-server round trip by bundling the two queries. The  extra column and`ORDER BY` is technically needed so you can safely assume the first row is the daily results and second is the monthly. In practice PostgreSQL won't re-order them with `UNION ALL` though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advise. I started PostgreSQL 2 weeks ago.I am still at a noob level. I'll study and try what you said. Thanks again!!

Comment: @VibhuthaKumarage No worries. The SQL injection thing applies to all SQL databases. Get used to thinking in terms of bind parameters, separating the data from the query text. See http://bobby-tables.com/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection .

Answer (score 1):

You can combine

```
SELECT a1 FROM t1 WHERE b1 = 'v1';
```

and

```
SELECT a2 FROM t2 WHERE b2 = 'v2';
```

to a single statement like this:

```
SELECT t1.a1, t2.a2 FROM t1, t2
   WHERE t1.b1 = 'v1' AND t2.b2 = 'v2';
```

provided that both queries return exactly one row.